# SQL UNION return more than on column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following sql statement. Which give the results all in one column. What I would like is to have the Dashboard Title returned once and then a row from each chart that belongs to a dashboard in another column.

```
SELECT 
    DashBoards.Title AS [Dash Board] 
FROM DashBoards 
GROUP BY DashBoards.Title 

UNION ALL

SELECT  
    Charts.Title AS Chart
FROM Charts 
INNER JOIN DashBoardCharts 
    ON Charts.ID = DashBoardCharts.ChartID 
INNER JOIN DashBoards 
    ON DashBoardCharts.DashBoardID = DashBoards.DashBoardID
```

There are three tables involved in this query:

```
CREATE TABLE Dashboards (
    DashboardID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Title CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ISDEFAULT BIT NOT NULL,
    CompanyID INTEGER NULL
);    
INSERT INTO Dashboards
VALUES (1,'Main DashBoard', 1, NULL);

CREATE TABLE Charts (   
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Title CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    SPName CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    XField CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    YField CHAR(50) NOT NULL
);    
INSERT INTO Charts
VALUES (1,'Alerting and Monitoring', 'spGetData', 'SumType', 'SumAmount');

CREATE TABLE DashboardCharts (
    DashBoardID INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Dashboards (DashboardID),
    ChartID INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Charts (ID)
);
INSERT INTO DashboardCharts
VALUES (1, 1);
```

The results that I am looking for are like so.

Dash Board                Chart
'Main Dashboard',    'Sales Analytics'
             'Alerting and Monitoring'
'Another Dashboard', 'Cost Management'
             'Settlement Management'

I.E.  only return the Dashboard title once along with all the charts that belong to that Dashboard.

Comment: Please post a small data sample from each of the tables, and a sample of what output you wish to achieve.  (don't post screenshots, please enter the data as text so we can port it to http://sqlfiddle.com if necessary)

Comment: Please see the original question.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: There's not enough data provided for `DashboardCharts` table to answer your question. The expected results are also not very clear - can you elaborate?

Comment: Ah, I see now.  Unless you want all the charts concatenated into one row as a string, you cannot just return the dashboard once followed by all charts. SQL will return results in a 2 dimensional format, and return them with the dashboard repeated for each chart. It is your application code's responsibility to format them for display how you want them, not the RDBMS'

Comment: Thank you for this information I will explore ways to handle this with in my application code.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.Title AS Dashboard, c.Title AS Chart
FROM  Dashboards AS d
      INNER JOIN DashboardCharts AS dc
        ON d.DashboardID = dc.DashboardID
      INNER JOIN Charts AS c
        ON dc.ChartID = c.ChartID
```

I've made some assumptions about your table structure and data based on the information provided. See [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a45d3/1).

For future SQL questions it would be helpful to have your table structure and data. Even something as simple as a CSV representation of your table and data greatly improves the quality of answers you'll receive, for example:

### Dashboards table

```
DashboardID,Title
1,'Main Dashboard'
2,'Alerting and Monitoring'
```

Comment: @user3157613 Please edit your original question with this information, it's difficult to read in a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the response the original question has not been updated.